# Use different value from a select dropdown that is created from a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

What this code does is, let the user select from a drop down list of schools. When the user selects the school they want the appropriate program appears in a second select drop down beside the school. The JS applies the same vales as the option. This is not what I want

What I want to do is have a different value applied to each program when selected.

```
$institution = [];

$institution['s1']  = ['Criminal Justice', 'Organizational Leadership'];
$institution['s2']  = ['Organizational Leadership'];


$( "#institution" ).change(function () {


    if ( $("#program option").length) {
        $("#program option:gt(0)").remove();
    }


    $( "#institution option:selected" ).each(function() {
        $program_val = $( this ).val();
    });


    $program = $institution[$program_val];


    if ( $program ) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $program.length; $i++) {
            $opt = '<option value="' + $program[$i] + '">' + $program[$i] + '</option>';
            $('#program').append($opt);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML.

```
<label class="label">Choose an Institution:</label>
<label class="select">
<select id="institution" name="institution">
<option value="0">--select--</option>
<option value="s1">School1</option>
<option value="s2">School2</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>

<label class="label">Choose a Program:</label>
<label class="select">
    <select name="program" id="program" onChange="setProgram();">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>
```

Not what I want 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRjxQ.png)

Comment: what value you need instead of same text?

Comment: Lets say you choose school1. which triggers Criminal Justice and Organizational Leadership to appear. The values I would want would be something like this. school1-crim-just and school1-org-lead. For school2 - school2-crim-just

Comment: solution provided by @Ravi MCA should work for you then

Comment: in this case, you have to add your own function which will translate your original array into what you need to output. you have to write either a switch case or IF/else statement and build array of your choice. Let me know if you need code example for proposed solution

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I'll look into that solution. I inherited this code and I'm a newbie when it come to JavaScript. I would love a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with reference to the latest comment added by you to the question, you can achieve what you need with following code.
You have to define your array in such a way where you can specify key and value separately.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$institution = [];

$institution['s1']  = [['school1-chrim-just','Criminal Justice'], ['school1-org-lead','Organizational Leadership']];
$institution['s2']  = [['school2-org-lead','Organizational Leadership']];

$( function(){

  $( "#institution" ).change(function () {

  var programHtml = '<option>--select--</option>';

    if( $( "#institution" ).val() != 0 ){

      $.each( $institution[$( "#institution" ).val()], function(index, ele){
         programHtml += '<option value="'+ ele[0] +'">'+ele[1]+'</option>';
      } );
    }

    $('#program').html( programHtml );
  });
} )

</script>

<label class="label">Choose an Institution:</label>
<label class="select">
<select id="institution" name="institution">
<option value="0">--select--</option>
<option value="s1">School1</option>
<option value="s2">School2</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>

<label class="label">Choose a Program:</label>
<label class="select">
    <select name="program" id="program">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>
```

Please check working **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5L00f5w2/3/)**

Comment: If your array has more values, then you can also populate this programatically

Comment: Done! Thanks Again!

Comment: Hey @K D!!! Thanks again for your help but I have one more question. What if I want to add another dependency based on the program. For ex. institution -->program --> courses.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I do not know what kind of value you want but you can use your index that easy way :

```
if ( $program ) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $program.length; $i++) {
            $opt = '<option value="' + $i + '">' + $program[$i] + '</option>';
            $('#program').append($opt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$institution = [];

$institution['s1']  = ['Criminal Justice', 'Organizational Leadership'];
$institution['s2']  = ['Organizational Leadership'];

$( function(){
  
  $( "#institution" ).change(function () {

  var programHtml = '<option>--select--</option>';

    if( $( "#institution" ).val() != 0 ){
      
      $.each( $institution[$( "#institution" ).val()], function(index, ele){
         programHtml += '<option value="'+ ele +'">'+ele+'</option>';
      } );
    }
  
    $('#program').html( programHtml );
  });
} )

</script>

<label class="label">Choose an Institution:</label>
<label class="select">
<select id="institution" name="institution">
<option value="0">--select--</option>
<option value="s1">School1</option>
<option value="s2">School2</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>

<label class="label">Choose a Program:</label>
<label class="select">
    <select name="program" id="program">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
</select>
<i></i></label>
```

Comment: The vales for the "Choose a Program" are not different. Values I want for s1 would be (s1-crim-just), (s1-org-lead for s1). Then For s2 (s2-crim-just)